# Characterization of vectors such that a linear transformation has the property $\|Mx\| > \rho(M)\|x\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, linear-transformations

Suppose $M \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear transformation. We know the operator norm induced by Euclidean 2-norm is lower bounded by $\rho(M)$, i.e., $\|M\|_2 \ge \rho(M)$. I find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650632/quick-question-matrix-with-norm-equal-to-spectral-radius/1055735#1055735) that the characterization of $M$ such that $\|M\|_2 = \rho(M)$.

I am wondering if there exists characterization of the set of vectors $U$ on which we have $\|Mu\|_2 > \rho(M) \|u\|_2$ for $u \in U$ when $\|M\|_2 > \rho(M)$. For instance, we know $\|M\|_2^2 = \rho(M^*M)$. If $\|M\|_2 > \rho(M)$,  it much be the vector $v$ corresponding to the largest singular value has the property. But in general, do we know how many vectors out there?

Comment: Your $U$ is not a subspace. For instance, $0\not\in U$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thanks for the comment. I changed the question.

Comment: If M is nilpotent you are looking at all x such that $Mx\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get an explicit characterization in general: it depends too much on the structure of $M$.

On one extreme, if $M$ is nilpotent, then $U=\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$.

If you think about the complement of $U$, those would be the vectors with $\|Mu\|\leq\rho(M)\,\|u\|$. This clearly includes all eigenvectors, but it is not necessarily a subspace: if
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix},\ \ u=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix},\ \ v=\begin{bmatrix} -1\\1/2\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$
Mu=u,\ \ \ \ \ Mv=-v. 
$$
Also, $\rho(M)=1$, and 
$$
\|Mu\|=\|u\|,\ \ \ \|Mv\|=\|v\|,\ \ \ \|M(u+v)\|=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\frac{\sqrt5}2>\frac12=\|u+v\|.
$$
So neither $U$ nor its complement are subspaces in general.